# Mensuration in 3D - Part of a sphere

Tags: integration, area, volume

> Consider the sphere of radius $r$ centered at 0 and the two great circles of the sphere lying on the xy and xz planes. A part of the sphere is *shaved off* in a such a manner that the cross section of the remaining part, perpendicular to the X-axis, is a **square with vertices on the great circles**. Compute the volume of the remaining part.

I'm not able to visualize even a bit of what's happening, in 3D. How is the cross section a square, and not a circle?

Also, as far as I know, a great circle is one that has the same center as its sphere.

Could someone please explain what's going on here, possibly with the help of figures/diagrams? All help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "remaining part" looks like a rugby ball with 4 sides, with each side more flatten.

For each $x \in [-1,1]$, the cross section is the square/diamond formed by the points $(0, k), (k, 0), (0, -k), (-k, 0)$ in the $yz-$plane, where $k^2+x^2=1$.

Here's [a 3D visualization, showing half of the solid](https://www.google.com/search?q=z%20%3D%20sqrt%281-%28abs%28x%29%2Babs%28y%29%29%5E2%29). Some axes were swapped due to Google chart plotter's limitation. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wERKy.png)

Comment: How did you draw it? Which software?

Comment: Also why is it a square/diamond?

Comment: The "software" is just Google (https://search.googleblog.com/2012/03/graphing-on-googlecom-now-in-3d.html).

Comment: It's a square because that's what the instruction asked for: "square with vertices on the great circles". You can verify that the cross section in the answer fits that description (1) it's a square (2) the vertices lie on the great circles.